# Python numpy: Dimension [0] in vectors (n-dim) vs. arrays (nxn-dim)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently wondering how the numpy array behaves. I feel like the dimensions are not consistent from vectors (`Nx1` dimensional) to 'real arrays' (`NxN` dimensional).

**I dont get, why this isn't working:**

```
a = array(([1,2],[3,4],[5,6]))
concatenate((a[:,0],a[:,1:]), axis = 1)
# ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

It seems like the `:` (at `1:]`) makes the difference, but (`:0` is not working)

Thanks in advance!

*Detailled Version: So I would expect that `shape(b)[0]` references the **vertical** direction in (`Nx1` arrays), like in an 2D (`NxN`) array. But it seems like dimension `[0]` is the **horizontal** direction in arrays (`Nx1` arrays)?*

```
from numpy import *

a = array(([1,2],[3,4],[5,6]))
b = a[:,0]
print shape(a)  # (3L, 2L), [0] is vertical
print a         # [1,2],[3,4],[5,6]
print shape(b)  # (3L, ), [0] is horizontal
print b         # [1 3 5]

c = b * ones((shape(b)[0],1)) 
print shape(c)  # (3L, 3L), I'd expect (3L, 1L)
print c         # [[ 1.  3.  5.], [ 1.  3.  5.], [ 1.  3.  5.]]
```

*What did I get wrong? Is there a nicer way than*

```
d = b * ones((1, shape(b)[0]))
d = transpose(d)
print shape(d)  # (3L, 1L)
print d         # [[ 1.], [ 3.], [ 5.]]
```

*to get the (`Nx1`) vector that I expect or want?*

Comment: `a` is 2 dimensional, `b` is one dimensional. Why do you say things are vertical and horizontal? With `b` one dimensional, it doesn't distinguish between horizontal and vertical (neither does `a`; it just has two dimension, perhaps called first and second dimension).

Comment: Or perhaps you're just thinking about the order of dimensions. That is more related to the way C orders/indexes multi-dimensional arrays: Python is not a mathematics language, it's a programming language. Hence it follows some logic of the underlying structure (in this case C, in which it is written).

Comment: What I dont get is, why `b`'s first dimension `[0]` ("horizontal", so the --- direction) ist not aligned with the first dimension `[0]` of `ones()` ("vertical" so the | direction). See the line `c = b * ones((shape(b)[0],1))`. After selecting a row from `a` with `b = a[:,0]` a (`Nx1`) array would be great

Comment: I may not be able to word it in your terminology, but I would say it as follows: `ones((b.shape[0], 1))` results in a `(3, 1)` array. `b` has a single dimension, and shape `(3,)`. Thus, multiplying `ones(...)` with `b` (left or right side doesn't matter here), will broadcast to the right dimension: thus, `ones(...)` gets broadcasted to a `(3, 3)` array, since the last (right-most) dimension of `b` is `(3,)`, and the 1 in the shape of `ones` can get broadcasted. If you'd try `ones(3, 2)`, you'll find this won't work, since the right dimension can't be broadcasted to that of `b`.

Comment: Thanks Evert! Ok so let me emphasize one part of my question: What is the easiest way to get `b` with a shape of `(3,1)`?

Comment: @Ben: Are you, by any chance, a MATLAB user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two overall issues here.  First, `b` is *not* an `(N, 1)` shaped array, it is an `(N,)` shaped array.  In numpy, 1D and 2D arrays are different things.  1D arrays simply have no direction.  Vertical vs. horizontal, rows vs. columns, these are 2D concepts.

The second has to do with something called "[broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)".  In numpy arrays, you are able to broadcast lower-dimensional arrays to higher-dimensional ones, and the lower-dimensional part is applied elementwise to the higher-dimensional one.

The broadcasting rules are pretty simple:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> they are equal, or
>
> one of them is 1

In your case, it starts with the last dimension of `ones((shape(b)[0],1))`, which is `1`.  This meets the second criteria.  So it multiplies the array `b` elementwise for each element of `ones((shape(b)[0],1))`, resulting in a 3D array.

So it is roughly equivalent to:

```
c = np.array([x*b for x in ones(shape(b))])
```

**Edit:**

To answer your original question, what you want to do is to keep both the first and second arrays as 2D arrays.

`numpy` has a very simple rule for this: indexing reduces the number of dimensions, slicing doesn't.  So all you need is to have a length-1 slice.  So in your example, just change `a[:,0]` to `a[:,:1]`.  This means 'get every column up to the second one'.  Of course that only includes the first column, but it is still considered a slice operation rather than getting an element, so it still preservers the number of dimensions:

```
>>> print(a[:, 0])
[1 3 5]
>>> print(a[:, 0].shape)
(3,)
>>> print(a[:, :1])
[[1]
 [3]
 [5]]
>>> print(a[:, :1].shape)
(3, 1)
>>> print(concatenate((a[:,:1],a[:,1:]), axis = 1))
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks ! Could you please elaborate how to get something like `concatenate((a[:,0],a[:,1:]), axis = 1)` working?